# RaiseCanExecuteChanged called while await causes deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, prism, async-await, prism-4

I am using WPF and `DelegateCommand` from PRISM and have the following problem:

I start an async operation like:

```
public async void ProgramDevice()
{
    var result = await FirmwareLoader.DownloadFirmwareAsync();
}
```

Inside this method an event is fired which I registered to and should update my `DelegateCommand` so it can't be executed:

```
//UiCommand is of type DelegateCommand
Engine.IsProgrammedChanged += 
    (s, e) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => UiCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged());
```

Now I have the problem, that the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` causes a deadlock (I checked and the `Dispatcher.Invoke` does not cause it, because when I e.g. show a MessageBox instead it works fine).

Am I doing something wrong or how can I work around this problem?

Comment: What does your UI thread do (i.e. what is its call stack) when the deadlock happens?

Comment: @svick: The `ProgramDevice` method is waiting at the "await" as expected and the event handler enters the `Invoke` and hangs at the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`. Call stack seems fine (DownloadFirmwareAsync -> OnIsProgrammedChanged -> AnonymousMethod)...

Comment: @chrfin: Please post the entire call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
It was not the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`, but the actual `CanExecute` which is triggered by it. In there I had an `AsyncLock` which waited for the programming task to be finished, before returning the value I use to descide if `UiCommand` can be executed --> deadlock as the programming task triggered it...

I solved it by simple using the "sync" property (which does not use the lock and just returns the current value/stat) of the value I need.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already solved your problem, but I thought I'd give a more general solution that will help you prevent such deadlocks in the future.

In your case, you could easily avoid this deadlock by using [`ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) like this:

```
var result = await FirmwareLoader.DownloadFirmwareAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What this does is allows the continuation to be performed on a different thread than the original. Doing so is not always possible, since a lot of times you need the continuation to be performed on the UI thread, but for this question I don't believe that's the case. So basically, the best practice is to always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless you need to resume execution from the original thread.

[This article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) explains in detail why these kind of deadlocks happen and how to avoid them. Another recommended read is [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I already knew that and I am using `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever possible. In this case it is not possible as the `ProgramDevice` method access the UI after the `async` call, which I left out here to keep the code short.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong or how can I work around this problem?

1. Method `Dispatcher.Invoke` blocks working thread until UI thread makes all updates
2. UI thread uses some resources locked by working thread (through `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` -> `CanExecute` method chain in the above code) and blocks
3. Deadlock since worker thread waits for UI thread to finish update and UI thread waits worker thread to release locked resources

A possible way to ensure no deadlocks is to **asynchronously invoke updates on UI thread** using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

```
//UiCommand is of type DelegateCommand
Engine.IsProgrammedChanged += 
    (s, e) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UiCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged());
```

This way UI thread will wait for a moment when working thread releases locked resources and then will update. But there will be no deadlock.